# bash script fails to run under ksh

Tags: linux, shell-script, ksh

I have below script which run successfully if i use `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

The same script is getting *unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"`* error while using `#!/bin/ksh`.

Why is that?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#--------------------
# Command variables
#--------------------
ECHO=/usr/bin/echo
SED=/usr/bin/sed
EXPR=/usr/bin/expr
EGREP=/usr/bin/egrep
DATE=/usr/bin/date
CUT=/usr/bin/cut

#--------------------
# Local variables
#--------------------
shopt -s extglob
SHELLNAME=$(basename $0)
GRANT_RAW_AMT=''
GRANT_AMT=0
GRANT_FILE=''
FILE_BN=''
COMPANY=''
EMAIL_GRANT=''
EMAIL_RECIPIENTS=$(${ATAS_SHELL}/get_global_constant.sh RESP RESP_CASH_RECIEPT)
EMAIL_RETURN=$(${ATAS_SHELL}/get_global_constant.sh RESP CASH_RECEIPT_SENDER)
RESP_DIR=${ATAS_RESP}/$(${ATAS_SHELL}/get_global_constant.sh RESP RESPDIR)
RESP_LOG=${ATAS_RESP}/log/${0##*/}.$(/usr/bin/date +%y%m%d).$(/usr/bin/date +%H%M).log

#--------------------------------------------
#  Determine the amount of grant for the company
#--------------------------------------------
  GRANT_RAW_AMT=000078753603
  unpadded_amt=${GRANT_RAW_AMT##+(0)} # trim leading 0's -- otherwise a value that starts with
                              # 0s can be treated as octal rather than decimal.
  printf -v GRANT_AMT '%d.%02d' "$(( unpadded_amt / 100 ))" "$(( unpadded_amt % 100 ))"
  EMAIL_GRANT=${EMAIL_GRANT}${COMPANY}'\t$'${GRANT_AMT}'\n'
${ECHO} ${EMAIL_BODY1}${EMAIL_GRANT}
#--------------------------------------------
#  End of Program
#--------------------------------------------
echo >> ${RESP_LOG}
${ECHO} "${SHELLNAME} completed"
exit 0
```

Comment: Because ksh and bash use 2 different languages. It would probably run if it was written for sh. You have to find what in this script are bashisms.

Answer (score 4):

`shopt -s extglob` is bash-specific (`shopt` alone is bash-specific, `bash` is the only shell to have two sets of options)

The `extglob` option in `bash` enables support for the ksh extended globs. It's not needed in ksh, though note that in ksh those globs are not recognised when used in variables.

`printf -v` is a `bash` extension. It's not support and not needed in ksh93 because there, command substitution doesn't fork a subshell. So instead of:

```
printf -v var ...
```

use

```
var=$(printf ...)
```

or in ksh93:

```
var=${ printf ...;}
```

if arguments to `printf` are supposed to make changes to the environment (like in `${foo=bar}` or `$((n++))`)
.
(though note that it strips trailing newline characters).

Also note that ksh93 does support floating point arithmetics, contrary to `bash`, so you don't need to resort to this kind of hack.

Other than that, I can't see anything in there that could explain the error message you're getting.